# Java submit form when clicks on button

Tags: forms, submit

I want to run the function: activity.insertAvailability, when the users clicks on the button.
At this moment I'm hardcoding the variables in the function.

When I run the function out of the table, the function works perfect.
Now I want to run the function, when the users clicks on the save button.

Here is the code

```
HTMLCode+="<br /><div align='center'><table class='TableBorder'>";

HTMLCode+="<tr class='TableData2'><td colspan='2'><br /><input class=SolidButton                  type='submit' value='Save' onClick='activity.insertAvailability(userSession.getDAOLayer().getConnection(), 34,  2503,'AM'', 1, 'test'');' /><br /><br /></td></tr>";

HTMLCode+="</table></div><br /><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Is "activity.insertAvailability" a java function? If yes, 
You should achieve this by a Ajax call. you can get started [here](http://javapapers.com/ajax/getting-started-with-ajax-using-java/).

Answer (score 0):

you have some typo errors here:

Change

```
onClick='activity.insertAvailability(userSession.getDAOLayer().getConnection(), 34,  2503,'AM'', 1, 'test'');'
```

with

```
onClick=\"activity.insertAvailability(userSession.getDAOLayer().getConnection(), 34,  2503,'AM', 1, 'test');\"
```